# WebScraping - BS4 only finds tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I work on a script that automatically compares prices for games on different websites (instantgaming, G2A, etc.). Following script works for some sites, but for others it won't. Code looks like this:

```
import bs4
import requests
res1 = requests.get('https://www.g2a.com/?search=dead%20by%20daylight')
res1.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res1.text,'html.parser')
elems = soup.find('div', {'id': 'content-landing'})
children = elems.find('div', {'class': 'mp-product-info'})
price = children.find('strong', {'class': 'mp-pi-price-min'})
price.text.strip()
```

The problem is that the price variable contains the correct tag

```
<strong class="mp-pi-price-min"></strong>
```

But it does not store the price (According to the browser, it should look like this:)

```
<strong class="mp-pi-price-min">10,16€</strong>
```

Doing the same code with a CSS-Selector instead, returns the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug, you'll see that when you request that page, it'll call via `XHR`a service that return the games and prices.

You'll need to stripe what you don't want, parse it as json and get the results.

Here's an example of that call:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import json

response = requests.get('https://www.g2a.com/lucene/search/filter?jsoncallback=jQuery111002521088376353553_1491736907010&skip=28837%2C28838%2C28847%2C28849%2C28852%2C28856%2C28857%2C28858%2C28859%2C28860%2C28861%2C28862%2C28863%2C28867%2C28868%2C28869%2C29472%2C29473%2C29474%2C29475%2C29476%2C29482%2C29486%2C33104&minPrice=0.00&maxPrice=640.00&cn=&kr=&stock=all&event=&platform=0&search=dead+by+daylight&genre=0&cat=0&sortOrder=popularity+desc&start=0&rows=12&steam_app_id=&steam_category=&steam_prod_type=&includeOutOfStock=false&includeFreeGames=false&_=1491736907012')
json_object = json.loads('{"data":%s}}' % (response.content.decode("utf-8").replace("jQuery111002521088376353553_1491736907010(", "")[:-2].replace("\'", "")))
for game in json_object["data"]["docs"]:
    print ("Name: %s (Price: %s)" % (game["name"], game["minPrice"]))
```

It'll print:

> Name: Dead by Daylight STEAM CD-KEY GLOBAL (Price: 10.16)
>
> Name: Dead by Daylight STEAM CD-KEY LATAM (Price: 5)
>
> Name: Dead by Daylight - Of Flesh and Mud DLC STEAM CD-KEY GLOBAL (Price: 4.99)
>
> Name: Dead by Daylight Deluxe Edition STEAM CD-KEY GLOBAL (Price: 13.99)
>
> Name: Dead by Daylight STEAM CD-KEY RU/CIS (Price: 4.95)
>
> Name: Dead by Daylight - The 80s Suitcase DLC STEAM CD-KEY GLOBAL (Price: 2.99)
>
> Name: Dead by Daylight STEAM CD-KEY SEA (Price: 6)

Also notice that you'll need to change `&search=...` part for the game that you want to search (urlencoded) and `_=` part for the current unix timestamp.